# Add dynamic values for ID, href and aria-controls using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add the dynamic values for the attributes(href, id, aria-controls), so that i can toggle down the text in multiple places for a single page. Just for your reference i have added "href="#0_read_more", aria-controls="0_read_more", id="0_read_more" in three places in the provided sample code. As well i have increment the values for other two div sections like given in the sample html code. Kindly help me out on this..

Thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="image-text">
 <a href="#0_read_more" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="0_read_more" class="collapsed">
                  Read More</a>
 <div id="0_read_more" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"><div>
</div>

<div class="image-text">
 <a href="#1_read_more" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="1_read_more" class="collapsed">
                  Read More</a>
 <div id="1_read_more" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"><div>
</div>

<div class="image-text">
 <a href="#2_read_more" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="2_read_more" class="collapsed">
                  Read More</a>
 <div id="2_read_more" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"><div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code? We can't help you if we don't see your code

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: Hi Jasper, Thanks for your response,please check with above sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsed').each(function(i){
        var a = '#'+ (i++)+'_read_more';
        $(this).attr('href',a);
    });
    $('.collapsed').each(function(i){
        var b = (i++)+'_read_more'  ;
        $(this).attr('aria-controls',b);
    });
    $('.collapse').each(function(i){
        var c = (i++)+'_read_more' ;
        $(this).attr('id',c);
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-text">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                  Read More</a>
    <div class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="image-text">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                  Read More</a>
    <div class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="image-text">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                  Read More</a>
    <div class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{$("#mydiv").append("<div class='image-text'><a href='#"+i+"_read_more' data-toggle='collapse' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='"+i+"_read_more' class='collapsed'>Read More</a><div id='"+i+"_read_more' class='collapse' aria-expanded='false' style='height: 0px;'><div></div>");
}     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response buddy, since contents are author-able, so i cannot implement this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set attribute for any DOM element using Jquery as follows,

```
<script>
function setAttributesDynamically(){

  $("SELECTOR").attr("href", "YOUR_URL"); // selector may be Id, class, tagname etc.
  $("SELECTOR").attr("id", "YOUR_ID");
  $("SELECTOR").addClass("CLASS_NAME");

}

</script>
```

Call `setAttributesDynamically()` wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response buddy, the above code will not work.

Comment: Why? what you want exactly? do you want to create DOM in javascript dynamically and append somewhere?

Comment: Hi buddy, the above code will work, but it wont suits for my existing code.